# Mouse-over black highlight in Zurb Foundation on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, sass, zurb-foundation

I am new to coding in general, and new to Ruby on Rails in the last couple months. I just started working with Zurb Foundation today to try it out for something on which I am working, as opposed to using Bootstrap.

The issue I am running into is that when I hover over a link (for example, in the footer), the link highlights with a black background.

I have been through the sass files and the css file that installs with Foundation and I just cannot for the life of me figure out what to edit and where to get this to stop.

What I want to accomplish is to have no change to the link when I hover over - just let the user click.

As I said, I'm new to Rails and coding as a whole, so I don't actually even know what files I should include snippets of to help answer the question... so some direction on that is helpful too.

Any help very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using other style on your application, something like a scaffold for generator, scaffold will generate scaffold css.
I'm use scaffold and i'm having `scaffold.css.scss` on my apps, Here's style of link on `scaffold.css.scss`

```
a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

You should remove style of link or you can remove scaffold style on your apps if you won't it.

Zurb-Fondation do not have style link with a black background, by default.

If you don't have other style on your app and only use zurb-fondation you should find style of link that bring about an issue

Comment: Brilliant - thank you so much! That was driving me crazy. To implement what you said, I deleted the scaffold.css.scss file. 

Looking back the misstep would be when I generated a scaffold, I didn't use "--skip-stylesheets".

Thank you again! I marked your answer as correct.